# New declaration is containing garbage value and Heap corruption while using delete

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to read an ANSI formatted file and converting this to binary.I'm declaring two dynamic memory allocation like this: `char* binary_reverse = new char;`  and `char * binary = new char;`

While debugging I see this(binary) contains too many garbage values. Why is it so?

I'm deleting these like: delete binary_reverse;  delete binary;
However, during delete its giving me error:

> 'ASCIItoBinary.exe': Loaded 'D:\TryingBest\Reactice\ASCIItoBinary\Debug\ASCIItoBinary.exe', Symbols loaded.
>   'ASCIItoBinary.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'ASCIItoBinary.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'ASCIItoBinary.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'ASCIItoBinary.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
>   HEAP[ASCIItoBinary.exe]: Heap block at 00241ED0 modified at 00241EFD past requested size of 25
>   Windows has triggered a breakpoint in ASCIItoBinary.exe.

Here is how I'm doing code:

```
#include <cstring>

void AtoB(char * input)
{
    unsigned int ascii; //used to store ASCII number of a character
    unsigned int length = strlen(input);
    //cout << " ";
    for (int x = 0; x < length; x++) //repeat until the input is read
    {
        ascii = input[x];
        char* binary_reverse = new char;       //dynamic memory allocation
        char * binary = new char;
        //char binary[8];
        int y = 0;
        while (ascii != 1)
        {
            if (ascii % 2 == 0)    //if ascii is divisible by 2
            {
                binary_reverse[y] = '0';   //then put a zero
            }
            else if (ascii % 2 == 1)    //if it isnt divisible by 2
            {
                binary_reverse[y] = '1';   //then put a 1
            }
            ascii /= 2;    //find the quotient of ascii / 2
            y++;    //add 1 to y for next loop
        }
        if (ascii == 1)    //when ascii is 1, we have to add 1 to the beginning
        {
            binary_reverse[y] = '1';
            y++;
        }

        if (y < 8)  //add zeros to the end of string if not 8 characters (1 byte)
        {
            for (; y < 8; y++)  //add until binary_reverse[7] (8th element)
            {
                binary_reverse[y] = '0';
            }
        }

        for (int z = 0; z < 8; z++)  //our array is reversed. put the numbers in the rigth order (last comes first)
        {
            binary[z] = binary_reverse[7 - z];
        }
        //printf("the Binary is %s",binary);
        //cout << binary;   //display the 8 digit binary number

        delete binary_reverse;     //free the memory created by dynamic mem. allocation
        delete binary;
    }
}
```

I want the exact binary values in "binary". NOT the binary values along with garbage?How to eliminate the garbage values? How to avoid the heap corruption?

Comment: `char* binary_reverse = new char; ` and `char * binary = new char;` - so you allocate 1 byte for storage

Comment: Off topic: save a bit of code: `else if (ascii % 2 == 1)` can just be `else`. When dealing with a single binary bit it's value will either be 1 or 0. If it's not one, it must be the other.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are allocating just 1 character with the `new char` commands. You want to allocate more, using `new char[9]`. Since you are printing out a maximum of 8 bits, you need one extra char for the null terminator. Be sure to set `binary_reverse[y]=0` at the end of the string.

And then `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

But that said, you should be using `std::string` or `std::vector` instead...

Comment: I tried this. like new char[8] and delete [] , its still having same issue

Comment: What you have posted will never work, so you should post something that has a chance of working (i.e. with `new char[8]`).

Comment: I've updated the answer. You need a null terminator at the end of your string.

Comment: I did this char* binary_reverse = new char[9];  and delete [] binary_reverse;. This I did also for binary. Still heap is getting corrupted.Anyone tried this with windows? Any exact solution to this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there are a bunch of things wrong in here almost all of them stem from not terminating the output string, and then heading offf in the wrong direction looking for a fix.

I'm going to ignore the error in

```
char* binary_reverse = new char;
```

other than to say OP needed more storage.

```
char* binary_reverse = new char[8];
```

The correct approach is to go back to the temporary allocation it looks like OP started with and add an extra byte to contain the string's null terminator. And then use that space for a null terminator.

Without the null terminator, you don't have a string. You have a binary blob. The printing routines, all c-style string routines, count on that terminator being there. Without it they don't know where the string ends and head off into the wild blue yonder looking for it. Often bad stuff happens. Or maybe it doesn't. What happens when you walk outside an array is undefined. Maybe it does what you want. Maybe it doesn't. No way to be sure. Nuking the site from orbit doesn't even work in this case.

So allocate temporary storage:

```
char binary_reverse[8]; // not using this one like a string so we don't need a terminator
char binary[9]; // printing this one. Need a terminator to know when to stop printing.
```

Later, after `binary_reverse` is constructed and then transferred to `binary`, `binary` needs to be terminated to become a string rather than just another anonymous binary blob.

```
binary[8] = '\0';
```

Now it can be printed.

Recommendations:

Visual Studio has an awesome debugger. Familiarize yourself with it. Save you much time it will.

If OP hadn't commented out the print statements odds are good someone would have spotted the main bug last night. Minimizing code is good, but OP removed the visible manifestation of the bug.

This code can be dramatically simplified. You know you want 8 bits because you're working in ascii (Well, actually ascii is 7 bits, but it's rare to see anything but 8 bit anymore). Turn the `while (ascii != 1)` into `for (int count = 0; count < 8; count++)` and test all 8 bits in the character. Save you a couple loops later because now you ALWAYS get 8 bits.

Comment: Still getting both the problems.Anyone tried writing same in VS and able to run successfully?

Comment: @TryingBest Total re-write of answer.